Conditional type for react props props
I need a type for my component. There are two fields title and description. They both can be undefined. But description cannot be without title.
Here is correct examples: <Component title='str' description='str'/> or <Component title='str'/> or <Component/> but this one is incorrect <Component description='str'/>
I try something like this
type Props = { title?: string; description?: string } | { title?: never; description?: never };

but that does not work

Something like this should work:
type Props = { title: string; description?: string } | {};

However, since {} represents any non-nullish value rather than strictly an "empty object," you should use Record<string, never> to explicitly define an empty object type:
type Props = { title: string; description?: string } | Record<string, never>;


You can define the type as below:
type Props = { title?: string } | { description?: string, title: string };

TS playground:
type Props = { title?: string } | { description?: string, title: string };

const Component  = ({}: Props) => false;

Component({ description: "My description" }); // Error
Component({ title: "My title" });
Component({ title: "My title", description: "My description" });
Component({});

